# How to create dynamic regex in javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, httpbackend

I want to use `$htppBackend` to mock some service. My problem is some of service url have parameter, ex: `http://domain/service1?param1=a&param2=b`

I need an regex which can reconize `http://domain/service1<whatever>` is correct for `http://domain/service1?param1=a&param2=b`. One thing, the first part `http://domain/service1` is not a constant, it can be `http://domain/service2/sth/anything`.

Please help. Thanks.

**Edit:**

I put my code here to make it easy to understand.

I have 4 api urls:

```
angular
    .module('moduleName')
    .constant('getApi', {
        attrList: 'http://domain/setup/attrList',
        eventList: 'http://domain/setup/eventList',
        vcList: 'http://domain/api/list1',
        getRaDetails: 'http://domain/abc/getDetails?raId={0}&bookId={1}'
    });
```

With `attrList`, `eventList` and `vcList`, they are ok with 
`$httpBackend.whenGET(getApi.attrList).respond(responseObject);`
`$httpBackend.whenGET(getApi.eventList).respond(responseObject);`
`$httpBackend.whenGET(getApi.vcList).respond(responseObject);`.

But the last one `getRaDetails`, it doesn't work with 
`$httpBackend.whenGET(getApi.getRaDetails).respond(responseObject);` because `raId` and `bookId` have different value each times.

Now I need a regex to make this rule -  `$httpBackend.whenGET(getApi.getRaDetails).respond(responseObject);` works with all `raId` and `bookId` value.

Hope it can explain my question more clearly. Thanks

Comment: That's always `http`?

Comment: what do you mean "correct"?

Comment: @lolka_bolka: I mean when I call `http://domain/service1?param1=a1&param2=b1` or `http://domain/service1?param1=a2&param2=b2`, it still reconize them as `$httpBackend.whenGET('http://domain/service1').respond(responseObject);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This's my working code:

```
_(getApis).each(function (api) {
                var val = api.value.split('?')[0].replace(/\//g, '\\/'),
                    reg = new RegExp(val);

                $httpBackend.whenGET(reg).respond(dummy[api.key]);
            });
```

Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

> I need an regex which can reconize http://domain/service1 is
>   correct for http://domain/service1?param1=a&param2=b

I don't think a regex is required here. Just simply check

```js
var stringPattern = "http://domain/service1";
var input = "http://domain/service1?param1=a&param2=b";

if ( input.indexOf( stringPattern ) == 0 )
{
   alert( "correct" );
}
else
{   
   alert( "Incorrect" );
}
```

Comment: that will match on the input of "http://domain/service1/path2" as well, which doesn't seem like what the author wanted.

Comment: @Paul I am checking if the `index` is 0. How will it match something else?

Comment: `http://domain.com/` will have an index of 0 on `http://domain.com/path1` as well as `http://domain.com/path2`, etc.  so my point is that if he wants the pattern to match the authority and path of the input, your suggestion won't guarantee that.

Comment: @Paul But that is precisely what `stringPattern` will have. If `stringPattern = "http://domain/service1";` how will it match `"http://domain/service2";` ?

Comment: @AdamKonieska By the look of it OP is looking to match a URL (hence a regex is requested). So if URL has the pattern it should match. Not sure if OP only want string after `?`

Comment: @Paul it will but I am checking `index == 0`, so it will still show incorrect

Comment: No, it won't.  I just tested it to make sure I'm not crazy.  `"http://domain/service1/path2".indexOf("http://domain/service1")` will, in fact, equal 0.  because the input starts with the pattern.

Comment: @Paul That is fine. OP has specifically mentioned `http://domain/service1<whatever>`. Please check.

Comment: I think we're reading the question differently. I think he means that the authority and path of the input URL should match the authority and path of the provided pattern, regardless of querystring values.  Not that the input should simply start with the URL pattern.

Comment: @Paul `I think we're reading the question differently.` Yes apparently :). Maybe we will just agree to disagree on it. You can post your answer having the solution which you just described.

Comment: @gurvinder372, @Paul: thanks for looking at my question. It's what I mean `I think he means that the authority and path of the input URL should match the authority and path of the provided pattern, regardless of querystring values. Not that the input should simply start with the URL pattern`. Sorry because of my bad English. I update question with my real code for more details. Thanks.

Comment: @gurvinder372: I need a regex to make $httpBackend understand that, it's easy to check but I don't know how to put `$httpBackend.whenGET(regex).respond(responseObject);` in `alert( "correct" );`

Answer (score 0):

So, if you are parsing Urls, it's best to use the URL object in JavaScript:

```
var input = 'http://domain/abc/getDetails?raId={0}&bookId={1}';
var test = 'http://domain/abc/getDetails';

var testUrl = new URL(test);
var inputUrl = new URL(input);
```

then test the various bits:

```
if(testUrl.pathname === inputUrl.pathname){
   //  they both have /abc/getDetails as the path
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I need a regex for `$httpBackend` understand that.

Comment: No you don't, from the documentation:  "HTTP url or function that receives a url and returns true if the url matches the current definition."  https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngMock/service/$httpBackend